# CORS policy: Response to preflight request - JavaScript/SharePoint Server

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint, cors

I have an issue connecting to my SharePoint server. This issue occurs whenever I try connecting my code from the frontend to the SharePoint server, I do not have a backend for this.

Basically, I am trying to get the SharePoint API results directly via JavaScript. I am uncertain why this error keeps popping up. Is there something wrong with my IIS configuration? Please do help me on this! Thank you ^_^

My code is as follows:

```
    function simpleSearchAPICall(searchUrl) {

        $.ajax({
            url: searchUrl,
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            
            complete: function(response){
                console.log("URL", searchUrl)
                console.log(response);
                // Handle the response data here
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error("ERROR:",error);
                // alert("An error occurred while making the request.");
            }
        });


    simpleSearchAPICall("http://www.test.com/_api/search/query?querytext='test'")
```

In my IIS on the SharePoint Server I have already set

```
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="X-MS-InvokeApp" value="1; RequireReadOnly" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

[image: CORS Error Message]